# NGINX not working with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, nginx

I've followed the following setup from https://johanndutoit.net/setup-nginx-for-codeigniter-on-ubuntu/. My `sites-available/default` file looks like:

```
server {
    server_name test.dev;
    root /var/www/html/ci-folder;

    index index.html index.php index.htm;

    # set expiration of assets to MAX for caching
    location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location / {
        # Check if a file exists, or route it to index.php.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

}
```

My config.php in my CodeIgniter file has the following included:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://test.dev/";
$config['index_page']       = "";
$config['uri_protocol']     = "REQUEST_URI";
```

My `/etc/hosts` file looks like:

```
127.0.0.1 test.dev
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 laptop-pc
```

But still [test.dev](http://test.dev) it redirects me to the "Welcome to NGINX!" page, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Clear cache from browser. Use another browser or private window to chack that.